# Double Nested Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have a navigation structure stored in a database. There are two models Navigation and Navigation Items.

```
class Navigation < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :navigation_items

  scope :all_items, -> { 
    includes(navigation_items: [:translations, children: :translations])
      .order('navigation_items.position asc')
      .where(navigation_items: { parent_id: nil })
    }

end
```

---

```
class NavigationItem < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :children, class_name: "NavigationItem", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "NavigationItem", foreign_key: 'parent_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :navigation
end
```

---

I setup the navigations in the application controller like this

```
def set_navigation
  @navigations = Navigation.all_items
  @navigation = []
  @footer_navigation = []
  @header_navigation = []

  if (main = @navigations.detect { |n| n.handle == "main" })
    @navigation = main.navigation_items
  end
  if (footer = @navigations.detect { |n| n.handle == "footer" })
    @footer_navigation = footer.navigation_items
  end
  if (header = @navigations.detect { |n| n.handle == "header" })
    @header_navigation = header.navigation_items
  end
end
```

---

I then loop through each navigation_item in the layout with a nested loop for the children.

All is working well except one thing. The navigation items all have a position tied to them. The parent items display in the correct order however the children are not obeying the order. Is there a way to also scope the children navigation items to order by position?

Comment: Would a `default_scope` for `NavigationItem` work? How about adding an `order` when calling `navigation_items`? I believe that the `order` for the `all_items` scope only applies to the initial query for `Navigation`, not to the subsequent queries for the `includes` relations.

Comment: I'm wrong about the `order` only applying to the initial query, at least on Rails 5.2.1. Which version of ActiveRecord are you on?

Comment: Hey @shanecav, also on rails 5.2.1. It is applying to the first level of navigation items but it is the sub items that are having trouble. I have tried default_scope with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this

you can use `default_scope` or association `condition`

```
class Navigation < ApplicationRecord
  # has_many :navigation_items, -> { where(parent_id: nil).order(position: :asc) }
  has_many :navigation_items, -> { where(parent_id: nil) }

  scope :all_items, -> { includes(navigation_items: [children: :children]) }
end
```

```
class NavigationItem < ApplicationRecord

  # has_many :children, -> { order position: :asc }, class_name: "NavigationItem", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :children, class_name: "NavigationItem", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "NavigationItem", foreign_key: 'parent_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :navigation

  default_scope -> { order position: :asc }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @PGill. Unfortunately it is still ordering the children incorrectly. I think I need to change the default order somehow to be order by parent.position then position.